# In Azure Devops I want my yaml pipeline only to execute after the previous execution of the same pipeline has completed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I tried `batch: true` setting described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema), but it seems to:

- ignore commits that are pushed when a pipeline is running. I want the last commit to trigger a pipeline *after* the current run of that pipeline has finished
- be ignored when you publish directly from CI by pressing build

Has someone found a way to configure a pipeline to run as I have described.

Comment: thats the default behaviour. build after push

Comment: If you do 5 commits, do you want 5 builds but each build should be run only after the previous finished?

Comment: @Sha The main objective is to prevent 2 pipeline runs to be performed in parallel. Whether _all_ builds are eventually run or not is less important, but I need the _latest_ to run, so I know that the last commit has been tested. 


The behaviour I see now is: given two consequetive commits commit-a and commit-b, commit-a triggers a build, but commit-b is ignored when `build: true` is set.

(BTW: thx for the formatting)

Comment: @JesperWermuth So maybe `batch: false` is what you need. than for each commit will be build.

Comment: Hi @JesperWermuth Did you get a chance to check out  Invoke REST API in below answer, how did it go?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk i believe ` batch: false` is the default. It allows jobs and stages of different pipelines to run in parallel.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT i have not tried it yet. Does your suggested solution mean that only one agent will ever be active, even if there is more than one agent in the pool to which your suggestion is applied

Comment: Hi @JesperWermuth Below solution is applied to multiple agents in the pool, and all the agents can be active.  I changed a little bit for below `URL suffix and parameters: ` to hard code the `DefinitionId` in the url. So the it can reduce the affects for other pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a **Invoke REST API** check on the agent pool. The rest api will get the previous build and evaluate its status. So when new build is queued targeting the agent pool. The Invoke REST API will be invoked, this new build will only start when the response of the rest api is evaluated to true.

Please check below steps：

1, **create a service connection to your azure devops organization.**

Go **Project Setting**--> **Service connections** under Pipelines-->Click **new service connection**--> select **Generic** to create a generic service connection.
[image]

Then Edit the service connection type the information shown in below screenshot. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to get a Personal access token.

[image]

2, **add Invoke REST API** check on the agent pool**.

Go **Project Setting**--> **Agent Pools** under Pipelines-->Select the **agent pool**--> Click the **3dots** -->Click **Approvals and checks**. 
[image].

3, Click the "**+**"--> Choose **Invoke REST API**

[image]

4, Edit the Invokde Rest API

Select the generic service connection to your azure devops created in the first step.

Set the fields as below:

- **URL suffix and parameters**: `_apis/build/builds?definitions=the DefinitionId of your pipeline&$top=2&queryOrder=queueTimeDescending&api-version=5.1`
- **Success criteria**: `eq(root['value'][1]['status'], 'completed')`

please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for more information about build rest api.

[image]

Note: Since the Invoke Rest api check is set on agent pool scope. It may have effects on other pipelines that target this agent pool. For example, if the desired yaml pipeline is waiting its previous run to complete. And now another pipeline targeting this same agent pool is triggered, it will have to wait for the previous run of desired yaml pipeline to complete too.

Comment: This answer was a great help, thank you! I did have to make a modification to the Success criteria however to account for multiple builds being created. If a second build gets created on the pipeline, the current build will get moved to the [1] index, and display as "InProgress" instead of "Completed", which will cause the check to fail on the remaining stages.

Comment: I modified the Success criteria to this: `or(and(eq(root['value'][0]['id'], variables['Build.BuildId']), eq(root['value'][1]['status'], 'completed')), and(eq(root['value'][1]['id'], variables['Build.BuildId']), eq(root['value'][2]['status'], 'completed')), and(eq(root['value'][2]['id'], variables['Build.BuildId']), eq(root['value'][3]['status'], 'completed')), and(eq(root['value'][3]['id'], variables['Build.BuildId']), eq(root['value'][4]['status'], 'completed')))` and it now works correctly with up to 4 queued builds on the pipeline. I also had to set the `$top` query param to 5