# Any way to require a variable be set at queue time?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I guess I could always add a script that fails if the variable isn't set, but I was hoping there was a way to prevent the pipeline from being queued if a specific variable is not set.

For example, we use ReleaseVersion for a number of things in the pipeline, including its eventual package name.  This has to be set at queue time.  If the person queuing the build forgets to set it, then it causes all kinds of issues, and we have to run the build again.

Any thoughts here?  (Yes, I know, we should pull this from a branch name or git tag, but that's not currently in the cards).

Comment: Seems it is proposed feature
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365977/required-variables-in-build-definitions.html

Comment: @Kontekst - So I see, from quite some time ago with no apparent movement.  It doesn't seem like it would be a difficult thing to implement, don't know why it got lost in the shuffle from UserVoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported in azure devops currently. You can go vote up on above [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365977/required-variables-in-build-definitions.html) or [create a new one yourself](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click **Suggest a feature** and choose **Azure devops**). Hope the development team will consider implementing this feature in the future sprint.

As workaround, you can add a script task that checks the variable and fails the pipeline on purpose.

If you want to check the variable before any tasks of pipeline running. You can use rest api checks. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422286/in-azure-devops-i-want-my-yaml-pipeline-only-to-execute-after-the-previous-execu/61455185#61455185) for detailed steps.

For your case, you need to define the Variable ReleaseVersion from the UI page and check the option `Let users override this value when running this pipeline`
 
[image]
[image]

Set the fields as below:

**URL suffix and parameters**: `_apis/build/builds?definitions={your definition id}&$top=1&statusFilter=all&api-version=5.1`

**Success criteria**: `ne(root['value'][0]['parameters'],'{"ReleaseVersion":""}')`

After you setup above checks. Your pipeline will check for the variable `ReleaseVersion` for currently build. The pipeline will fail to start if the `ReleaseVersion` is not set.

Comment: That's close enough for me.  Thanks