# Azure DevOps Run Powershell Before and After Code Deploy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to have a Powershell task that excutes once - at the start of a Release Pipleine?

The scenario is that a release may have multiple targets, however there is an API call (Coudflare) that I need to make before and after code has been deployed to each target.

I've looked into the Agentless Job, however the Invoke API task doesn't support Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use invoke api task to call Cloudflare API in the agentless job. You can have try creating a [Generic service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-generic) to connect to Cloudflare server.

Project settings-->Service connections-->New service connection-->Generic

[image]

Then you can use the Generic service connection in Invoke API task.  See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422286/in-azure-devops-i-want-my-yaml-pipeline-only-to-execute-after-the-previous-execu/61455185#61455185).

But, is there any problem if you add a powershell task on the top of your release pipeline to run before the code is deployed and another powershell task after the deploy task to run after the code has been deployed?

```
steps:
- powershell:
- task: other tasks
  ...
- task: deploy task
- powershell:
```